# date difference, multiple values one column relative to one in another

Tags: sql-server

```
order #| activity | start time | end time      |daydiff
a           b          null       dd/mm/yyyy      e-b
a           c          null       dd/mm/yyyy      e-c
a           d          null       dd/mm/yyyy      e-d
a           e        dd/mm/yyyy      null         null
a           f          null       dd/mm/yyyy      e-f
```

I need to calculate the difference in days between a date on one row of one column (start time) and multiple rows in a second column (end time) (start time-end time) so i can calculate the lapse time between the end time of activities b,c,d,f relative to the start time of e. for each activity in the end_time column, and group this by order. 
Context is that activity e is dependent on a,b,c,d,f but I dont know the order of these activities, so plan on using the end time of these predecessor activities to order them realtive to e. (this day difference will also then form psrt of a later step also)
I am a SQL novice and have no idea how I can do this or if it is even possible?

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide us the expected output.

Comment: I have added desired outcome, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATEDIFF( datepart , startdate , enddate )`

Example:

`SELECT DATEDIFF( day , starttime , endtime );`

That will return you the difference in days.

Read [more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that there is one non null value of start_time column within each order:

```
 Select o1.*, datediff(dd, o2.StartDate, o1.EndDate) as DayDiff from Orders o1
 join Orders o2 on o1.OrderID = o2.OrderID and o2.StartTime is not null
```